# Onenote - Link to Sharepoint sync folder

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote, sharepoint

Background: We use sharepoint in the office, recently we have started using the sync function that adds sharepoint folders as OneDrive drives.

I want to create a directory of folder and files that are frequently used, that opens directly on the file explorer (or the file itself), but as some people don't have OD on the same folder it won't work if I link it to the file location.

But if I add it as a sharepoint link it will open in the browser.

Does anyone know of a way to make the links so that everyone can use it, and so that it opens in the File explorer? Preferably on the sync folder.

Comment: Hi i know it's late, and closed but I think I've an answer:

In OneNote, add a link. 
Set the address to 'shell:OneDriveDocuments'
You get a security warning and the directory opens.
Tested on Windows 10, One Note 2016
Sorry I couldn't answer before it was closed.